# Noncommutative arithmetic mean geometric mean inequality and symmetric polynomials

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrices, oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, inequalities

While analyzing convergence speed of stochastic-gradient methods for convex optimization problems, Recht et al [(2011)](http://opt.kyb.tuebingen.mpg.de/opt11/invited.html) posed a tantalizing conjecture. It seems quite tricky, so after having struggled a bit with it, I decided to bring it to the attention of the MO community.

Among other questions, Recht and Re (RR) [**[1]**](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4184) pose the following *Arithmetic-Mean, Geometric-Mean* conjecture concerning symmetrized products:

> **RR.** Let $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ be symmetric positive definite matrices. Let $\pi \in \mathfrak{S}_n$, where $\mathfrak{S}_n$ denotes the symmetric group.  Let $P_{\pi} := \prod_{i=1}^n A_{\pi(i)}$. Then,
>   $$\begin{equation*}
>  \left\|\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\pi \in \mathfrak{S}_n} P_{\pi}\right\| \le \left\|\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n A_i\right)^n\right\|,
> \end{equation*}$$
>   where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the spectral norm.

Playing around a bit, it seems that in fact, the following much stronger conjecture should be true, but as of now, I don't know how to prove it---so I'm putting it out here. Hopefully, someone will be able to suggest to me potential areas of math where I could go to further educate myself about related inequalities.

> **(S., 2011).** Let $\sigma(\cdot)$ denote the singular value map, i.e., the map that associates to a matrix the vector of its singular values (arranged in decreasing order). And let $\prec_w$ denote [*weak majorization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization). Then, 
>   $$\begin{equation*}
>  \sigma^{1/n}\left(\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\pi \in \mathfrak{S}_n} P_{\pi}\right) \prec_w \sigma\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n A_i\right).
> \end{equation*}$$

---

**Notes.**

(a) The two matrix version of the my conjecture follows immediately from a stronger conjecture of Bhatia and Kittaneh that was actually recently resolved in Ref. [2].

(b) It seems that for random matrices, Recht and Re proved their conjecture (because everything just disentangles easily); see cited paper for details.

**REFERENCES**

**[1].** B. Recht and C. Re (2012). Beneath the valley of the noncommutative arithmetic-geometric mean inequality: conjectures, case-studies, and consequences.

**[2].** S. W. Drury, On a question of Bhatia and Kittaneh, Linear Algebra and its Applications, 437 (2012) pp. 1955--1960.

Comment: Since you are summing over the $n$th symmetric group while you have a list of $m$, rather than $n$, matrices, could you make the highlighted inequalities clearer by writing explicitly what the range of summation is on the right side ($i$ runs from what to what)?

Comment: @KConrad: thanks for catching that indexing typo. Now fixed. It is $n$ throughout.

Comment: The second statement should also have the summation index $i$ running explicitly from 1 to $n$. 

Comment: What is the "singular value map" in terms of the singular value decomposition? Does it associate to a matrix the diagonal matrix in is singular value decomposition?

Comment: @KConrad: thanks for helping me improve the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "The two matrix version of the my conjecture follows immediately from a stronger conjecture of Bhatia and Kittaneh that was actually recently resolved"?

Comment: @Betrand: In the two matrix case, the conjecture actually either follows directly, because it's just $\| |(AB+BA)/2|^{1/2} \| \le (1/2)\|A+B\|$ (for any unitarily invariant norm)...

Comment: Could it be that $ \|P_\pi\| \le \|((1/n) \sum_{i=1}^n A_i)^n\|$? Because then RR follows from this and triangle inequality. Note that because $A \ge0$, and we are in  a $C^*$-algebra, we have $\|A^n\| = \|A\|^{n}$ for all $n=2^k$ (of this form). (Because $\|A A \| = \|A^*A\| = \|A\|^2$.) So you had only to show $\|A_1 A_2\|  \le (1/4)\| A_1 + A_2\|^2$ in case $n=2$, say. Similarly so for $n=2^k$.

Comment: ED: I need to remark, however, I remember something vaguely, that such last (or whatever) estimates hold only in general if the algebra is commutative.

Comment: @hänsel alas, if it were only that simple! (the linked article of Recht and Re shows a nice counterexample I think); also, proofs are known now for $n$ a multiple of 3, but the general case is still open.

Comment: Hi Suvrit, have you seen [arXiv:2006.01510
 Recht-Ré Noncommutative Arithmetic-Geometric Mean Conjecture is False](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.01510)?

Comment: @i9Fn thanks for drawing my attention back to this question; yes, I did see that paper several months ago when working on: https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.06946 -- but I did not get a chance to update my question to remark on that (that SOS based countex then also breaks the singuar value majorization; however, the trace norm version of the conjecture is true, which is easy to see via a short calculation)....